# Dynamic creation of radio button in Html for IE

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, radio-button

Can anybody give me a working code for creating dynamic radio buttons in html (and javascript) which works in IE, Firefox and Chrome?

I saw a lot of codes in the internet, but none of them worked for me.

I also need them to have a label. And I don't want to use Jquery.

Tried this code:

```
function test() {
var element = document.createElement("input");
//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
element.setAttribute('value', 'source');
element.setAttribute('name', 'source'); 
element.setAttribute('id', 'source_id');
var foo = document.getElementById("divTxt");
foo.appendChild(element);
var newlabel2 = document.createElement("Label"); 
newlabel2.for = "source_id";
newlabel2.innerHTML = "first name ";
foo.appendChild(newlabel2);
}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? Show some of the simple alternatives you have found and explain in which sense it does not work.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I tried this code:

Comment: function test(){
var element = document.createElement("input");
 
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    element.setAttribute('value', 'source');
    element.setAttribute('name', 'source');
 element.setAttribute('id', 'source_id');


var foo =  document.getElementById("divTxt");
foo.appendChild(element);

var newlabel2 = document.createElement("Label");
    newlabel2.for = "source_id";
    newlabel2.innerHTML = "first name ";
foo.appendChild(newlabel2);
}

Comment: please somebody tell me how to put code here!

Comment: Theh code I sent, does not work in IE at all, it shows neither the button nor the label

Answer (score 3):

```
var radio1 = document.createElement('input');
radio1.id = 'myRadioId1';
radio1.type = 'radio';
radio1.name = 'radioGroup';
radio1.value = 'someValue1';

var radio2 = document.createElement('input');
radio2.id = 'myRadioId2';
radio2.type = 'radio';
radio2.name = 'radioGroup';
radio2.value = 'someValue2';

var label1 = document.createElement('label');
label1.htmlFor = radio1.id;
label1.innerHTML = 'label for radio1';

var label2 = document.createElement('label');
label2.htmlFor = radio2.id;
label2.innerHTML = 'label for radio2';
```

Appending to container:

```
var container = document.getElementById('mydivid');
container.appendChild(radio1);
container.appendChild(label1);
container.appendChild(radio2);
container.appendChild(label2);
```

If you need radio group, you should give them same names. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jphYt/1/)

Comment: `label1.setAttribute('for', radio1.id);` you need to do `label1.htmlFor=radio1.id;`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with the code (which you posted in a comment and I copied into the question) is that it contains only a function definition. The function is not called at all, so need to have a statement like `test()`. Moreover, the function postulates that there is an element with `id=divTxt` on the page, and that element must appear before the calling the function. The following code successfully creates a radio button element and its label and inserts them into an existing element on the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Demo</title>
<div id=divTxt></div>
<script>
function test() {
var element = document.createElement("input");
//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
element.setAttribute('value', 'source');
element.setAttribute('name', 'source'); 
element.setAttribute('id', 'source_id');
var foo = document.getElementById("divTxt");
foo.appendChild(element);
var newlabel2 = document.createElement("Label"); 
newlabel2.setAttribute('for', "source_id");
newlabel2.innerHTML = "first name ";
foo.appendChild(newlabel2);
}
test();
</script>
```

(You cannot use the `for` property in JavaScript; the property name is `htmlFor`, but it is probably simpler to set the `for` *attribute* as above.)

However, radio buttons should always appear in groups, due to their nature, so you should use a function with some arguments to generate a set of radio buttons according to a common pattern. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Demo</title>
<div id=divTxt></div>
<script>
function radio(name, value, text) {
var element = document.createElement("input");
var id = name + value;
element.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
element.setAttribute('value', value);
element.setAttribute('name', name); 
element.setAttribute('id', id);
var foo = document.getElementById("divTxt");
foo.appendChild(element);
var newlabel2 = document.createElement("label"); 
newlabel2.setAttribute('for', id);
newlabel2.innerHTML = text;
foo.appendChild(newlabel2);
}
radio('sex', '0', 'male');
radio('sex', '1', 'female');
</script>
```

You should minimally enhance this by adding code that adds line breaks between the items, or preferably put each pair of a button and its label inside a `div` elemebt.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Surely, I put the code in the <head> tags and called it somewhere. But it didn't work in IE. Does it work in IE for you? I use IE9

Comment: Yes, it works fine in IE, too. Your problem might be that the script code, including the call of the function, is inside the `head` element. Then the id `divTxt` is not defined, and the operation fails (you should see an error message in the console log). A simple solution is then to put the function call in a `script` element that appears at the end of `body`.